# split list in scala based on diff between neighbouring elements

Tags: scala, scala-collections

How do we split list in scala based on difference between neighbouring elements. For example given List(1,3,6,10,12,14) and difference 3, the function would return List(List(1,3),List(6),List(10,12,14)).

Can we user foldLeft to do that? I was trying to create a function

```
def splitDiff(list:List[Int],diff:Int) = 
     def func(list:List[List[Int]],m:Int):List[List[Int]] = //compare with last element
     list.foldLeft(List(List(0))).foldLeft(func)
```

But the inner function seems difficult? Any help?

Comment: it's not clear : you split after 3 (6 - 3 = 3) but you also split after 6 (10 - 6 = 4)

Comment: sorry i mean if diff >= 3, i split there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I have a solution, but I suspect one can do better:

```
(test.head :: test).sliding(2).toList.map( (pair: List[Int]) => (pair(1), pair(1) - pair(0)) )
                   .foldLeft(List(List.empty[Int])){ (acc, pair) => 
     if (pair._2 < 3) (pair._1 :: acc.head) :: acc.tail else List(pair._1) :: acc }
```

Note that this gives results in "doubly-reversed" order:

```
res3: List[List[Int]] = List(List(14, 12, 10), List(6), List(3, 1))
```

Which can be corrected by adding `.map(_.reverse).reverse` to the end of the function.

**EDIT** - alternate attempt:

```
def func(is: List[Int], diff: Int): List[List[Int]] = {
  def loop(is: List[Int], prev: Int, acc: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = is match {
    case Nil => acc
    case h :: t if (h - prev < diff) => loop(t, h, (h :: acc.head) :: acc.tail)
    case h :: t => loop(t, h, List(h) :: acc)
  }

  loop(is, is.head, List(List.empty[Int]))
}
```

Again, gives solution in doubly-reversed form.

Comment: to be quite frankly your solution but it looks a bit more complicated than it needs to be =)

Comment: Indeed, @Stefan Kunze. I worked on another attempt which looks nicer - in fact, seems much the same as your solution!

Comment: Haha, i didnt go through the troubleof creating a list of lists :) Just laying out the schematics.

Comment: Actually, I was a bit surprised that there wasn't a method on List (or rather, `TraversableLike`) similar to the existing `partition`, but dividing the sequence multiple times whereever a passed-in Boolean condition was met (`partition` only divides the list once). If I had a couple of calculations similar to this one to do, I'd probably look at pimping such a method first.

Comment: My initial thoughts were also on using partition. There must be an easy way to lift it up.

Answer (score 1):

One more solution using foldLeft:

```
scala> val x = List(1,3,6,10,12,14)
x: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 6, 10, 12, 14)

scala> val y = x.foldLeft((x.head,List[Int](),List[List[Int]]())) 
     ((x,y)=> if((y- x._1) <3) (y,y :: x._2,x._3) else (y,List(y), x._2 :: x._3))
y: (Int, List[Int], List[List[Int]]) = (14,List(14, 12, 10),List(List(6), List(3
, 1)))

scala> val ans = y._2 :: y._3
ans: List[List[Int]] = List(List(14, 12, 10), List(6), List(3, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pleas keep in mind that this is untested:

```
  def splitListDiff(li: List[Int], diff: Int): List[Int] =
        {
          li match {
            case hd :: tl => if (hd - tl < diff) hd :: splitListDiff(tl, diff) else return li ++ splitListDiff(tl, diff)
            case _ => return li
          }
        }
```

But you wanted a solution that leverages foldleft?

Answer (score 0):

The following works without additional reversing. Since the OP didn't say whether the list's elements are always in ascending order, I thought it'd be good to use `Math.abs` as well:

```
def splitDiff(diff: Int)(xs: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = xs match {
  case Nil      => Nil
  case h :: t   =>
    val head = h :: ((xs zip t) takeWhile {
      case (a,b) => Math.abs(b-a) < diff
    } map (_._2))
    head :: splitDiff(diff)(xs drop head.length)
}
```

The downside of this approach is that the tail gets zipped over and over again. However, this could easily be avoided by encapsulating the match and zipping only once at the beginning.